# Applying reference to another sheet to all cells

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have LibreOffice Calc file which has 2 sheets.

I wanted to reference Sheet1 from Sheet2, so I wrote function `=Sheet1.A1` in Sheet2 cell A1.

How do I apply this to *all* cells on Sheet2? (Sheet2.B5 = Sheet1.B5, ...)

I select all cells, but I have no idea what formula to write: `=Sheet1.????`

**Edit**:

Some clarification:

Reason I want to do this is that Sheet1 will have varying number of rows. So when I add new rows to Sheet1, then Sheet2 should just deal with it, without requiring me to apply same formula to new rows (which I sometimes forget to do).

That is why all cells in column should have this reference by default, not only subset of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just [drag the formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Copying_Formulas) from Cell Sheet2!A1 down and to the right; LO will adjust the cell reference accordingly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

To drag the formula, move the cursor over the little black box at the lower right of the Cell A1. The cursor will turn into a small cross-hair symbol. Now, click left and move the cursor down or to the left.

Comment: I tried this, but it only works for limited set of rows. I added some clarification to my post.